# No aparece "View" en el menú "View Controller"

Tags: xcode

Acabo de crear un proyecto en Xcode 8 y al tratar de editar el fondo de la pantalla veo que no puedo acceder al mismo porque no aparece la vista  "View" en el menú "View Controller".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en otro proyecto que tengo si que puedo verla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como activar esta vista.

Gracias.

Comment: Añadele la vista a mano y crea las relaciones con el first respoder

Comment: ¿Como se añade a mano?